# SQL query table 2x then combine results into 1 column

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am working with sqlite and have a language dictionary. I want to search the table once for a match in English then again to find the results in another language by matching foreign keys (to a Japanese character).

Currently, I can get the results by doing 2 queries and having 4 separate columns: text x2 and language x2.

How can I combine them into one column as new rows? I don't think that SQL's union is what I'm looking for.
I've also tried doing a select within a select to query the table twice, but the query time goes from ~700ms to ~1400ms on my laptop and I plan to use this in a mobile app, so I'd like to keep the speed down. I also am hoping to use a cshart sqlite ORM to be able to take these results and put them into a model that has a collection of the languages.

here is a sample query that I've tried (I've tried a bunch)

```
-- find the Character using the Reading's ChFKEY
select
    r.ID,
    r.Text,
    r.Language,
    reading.Text,
    rl.Language,
    r.ChID,
    r.KaID
from

-- first, find a dictionary match for English
(select
        r.ID,
        r.Text,
        rl.Language,
        r.ChID,
        r.KaID
    from Reading r
    join ReadingLanguage rl on r.RLID = rl.ID
    where r.RLID = 1
    and r.Text like 'food%')r
join Reading reading on reading.RLID in (8,9) -- find JapaneseOn, JapaneseKun
join ReadingLanguage rl on reading.RLID = rl.ID  --get the language text
and reading.ChID = r.ChID; -- use the character FKey to find matches
```

and here is a sample result from the above query:
"977"   "food, bait, prey, tempting profit" "English"   "ジ, ニ"  "JapaneseOn"    "284"   "128"
"977"   "food, bait, prey, tempting profit" "English"   "え, えば, えさ, もち" "JapaneseKun"   "284"   "128"

**edit**
here is what I'm hoping to get:
"977" "food, bait, prey, tempting profit" "English" "284" "128"
"977" "え, えば, えさ, もち" "JapaneseKun" "284" "128"
"977" "ジ, ニ" "JapaneseOn" "284" "128"

Comment: There's only one way to make the query return one column is by concatenating them with CONCAT or || depending on SQL implmentation of your RDBMS.

Comment: Is it  possible to have them as a new row?

Comment: The example outputs two rows with seven columns. What is the desired output?

Comment: My apologies, the sample output is what I get now. I'll update the post with a desired output.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** It occurred to me that I could do the entire thing to produce the dictionary results that I wanted and that I was thinking about it in the wrong way. I am now using group_concat to put the Japanese results together and to have the English in another column. This way no work is required in the c# to produce the results for the view.

```
    select
ID,
Text as English,
group_concat(Japanese) as Japanese,
Character
from
(
select 
    r.ID,
    r.Text,
    ch.Text as Character,
    reading.Text as Japanese
from
(
    (
    select
        r.ID,
        r.Text,
        rl.Language,
        r.ChID,
        rl.ID
    from Reading r
    join ReadingLanguage rl on r.RLID = rl.ID
    where r.RLID = 1 --English
    and r.Text like 'food%'
    )r
join Reading reading on reading.RLID in (8,9) --JapaneseOn, JapaneseKun
join ReadingLanguage rl on reading.RLID = rl.ID 
join Character ch on r.ChID = ch.ID --grab the kanji character
and reading.ChID = r.ChID
)
order by rl.ID desc --so that the hiragana shows up before the katakana
) 
group by Character;
```

The new result is
"34905" "food, provisions"  "かて,リョウ, ロウ"    "粮"

**EDIT The old version**
I got some help. It turns out that Union All is the way to go for this. The new query completes in 446ms (unless I order it) and I'm hoping that the ORM will put them into their parent objects correctly.

```
-- find the Character using the Reading's ChFKEY
-- 448 ms

select
    r.ID,
    r.Text,
    rl.Language,
    ch.Text as Character
from Reading r
join ReadingLanguage rl on r.RLID = rl.ID
join Character ch on r.ChID = ch.ID
where r.RLID = 1
and r.Text like 'food%'

union all

select
    r.ID,
    reading.Text,
    rl.Language,
    ch.Text as Character
from
(
    select
        r.ID,
        r.Text,
        rl.Language,
        r.ChID,
        r.KaID
    from Reading r
    join ReadingLanguage rl on r.RLID = rl.ID
    where r.RLID = 1
    and r.Text like 'food%')r
join Reading reading on reading.RLID in (8,9) -- find the JapaneseOn, JapnaeseKun
join ReadingLanguage rl on reading.RLID = rl.ID -- get the actual language
join Character ch on r.ChID = ch.ID -- get the japanese character that it belongs to
and reading.ChID = r.ChID
--order by r.ID
;
```

and the sample output is
"977"   "food, bait, prey, tempting profit" "English"   "餌"
"977"   "ジ, ニ"  "JapaneseOn"    "餌"
"977"   "え, えば, えさ, もち" "JapaneseKun"   "餌"